# Google cloud credentials totally hosed after attempting to setup boto

Tags: google-cloud-storage, boto, gcloud

I had a gcloud user authenticated and was running gsutils fine from the command line (Windows 8.1). But I needed to access gsutils from a python application so I followed the instructions here: 
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/gspythonlibrary#credentials

I got as far as creating a .boto file, but now not only does the my python code fail (boto.exception.NoAuthHandlerFound: No handler was ready to authenticate.). But I can't run bsutils from the command line any more. I get this error:

```
C:\>gsutil ls
You are attempting to access protected data with no configured
credentials. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/console#/project
and sign up for an account, and then run the "gcloud auth login"
command to configure gsutil to use these credentials.
```

I have run gcloud auth and it appears to work, I can query my users:

```
C:\>gcloud auth list
Credentialed Accounts:
 - XXXserviceuser@XXXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com ACTIVE
 - myname@company.name
To set the active account, run:
    $ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT`
```

I have tried both with the account associated with my email active, and the new serveruser account (created following instructions above). Same "protected data with no configured credentials." error. I tried removing the .boto file, and adding the secret CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET to my .boto file.

Anyone any ideas what the issue could be?

Comment: So I can get the command line gsutil working again, by calling "gcloud auth revoke" followed by  "gcloud auth login". But the python application is still very broken with: "boto.exception.NoAuthHandlerFound: No handler was ready to authenticate." error. Are there up-to-date instructions for getting the GS python binding working? The ones at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/gspythonlibrary#credentials are very out of date.

Answer (score 0):

So I think the latest documentation/examples showing how to use (and authenticate) Google Cloud storage via python is in this repo:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/storage/api

That just works for me without messing around with keys and service users.

Would be nice if there was a comment somewhere in the old gspythonlibrary docs pointing this out.